# I many-to-many relationship, get ID of pivot table

Tags: laravel

I have the following models in a many-to-many relationship:

```
class Event extends Model
{
    public function positions() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Position::class, 'position_events');
    }
}

class Position extends Model
{
    public function events() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Event::class, 'position_events');
    }
}

class PositionEvent extends Model
{
    public function position() {
        return $this->hasOne(Position::class, 'id', 'position_id');
    }

    public function event() {
        return $this->hasOne(Event::class, 'id', 'event_id');
    }
}
```

The `position_events` table looks like:

```
id | event_id | position_id
```

If `$event` is an instance of `Event`, I can get the related positions as:

```
$event->positions;
```

This gives me something like the following for each related Position:

```
{"id":4,"name":"Striker","created_at":"2019-04-02 16:19:57","updated_at":"2019-04-02 16:19:57","pivot":{"event_id":27,"position_id":4}}
```

Notice the `pivot` element. It only has `event_id` and `position_id` as properties, these are columns from the `position_events` table. How do I get it to have the `id` column from that table as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `withPivot()`, for example:

```
$this->belongsToMany(Position::class, 'position_events')->withPivot('id');
```